# Calculate differences scores between rows in a group_by

Tags: r, dplyr, difference

I am working with some match data and would like to work out the difference in goals between each team for each match.

I can get the score difference for the second team (in the diff column) but I can't work out how to calculate the goal difference for the *first* team. It should be the inverse of the goal difference for the second team (i.e. in the sample data set the "Growlers" should have `1` in the diff column and "Strike" should have `-1`).

```r
library(dplyr)

dat <-
  structure(
    list(
      Match = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3),
      Team = c("Growlers",
               "Rollers", "Strike", "Bandits", "Cats", "Blues"),
      Goals = c(1,0, 0, 1, 1, 2)
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,-6L),
    groups = structure(
      list(
        Match = c(895825, 895826, 895827),
        .rows = list(1:2, 3:4,
                     5:6)
      ),
      row.names = c(NA,-3L),
      class = c("tbl_df", "tbl",
                "data.frame"),
      .drop = TRUE
    ),
    class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df",
              "tbl", "data.frame")
  )

dat %>% 
    group_by(Match) %>% 
    mutate(diff = Goals - lag(Goals))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#> # Groups:   Match [3]
#>   Match Team     Goals  diff
#>   <dbl> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1 Growlers     1    NA
#> 2     1 Rollers      0    -1
#> 3     2 Strike       0    NA
#> 4     2 Bandits      1     1
#> 5     3 Cats         1    NA
#> 6     3 Blues        2     1
```

Created on 2019-02-26 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty way is to explicitly calculate the score for team 1 and team 2 as follows:

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(Match) %>% 
  mutate(
    diff = c(
      Goals[1] - Goals[2],
      Goals[2] - Goals[1] 
    )
  )

#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#> # Groups:   Match [3]
#>   Match Team     Goals  diff
#>   <dbl> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1 Growlers     1     1
#> 2     1 Rollers      0    -1
#> 3     2 Strike       0    -1
#> 4     2 Bandits      1     1
```